# I2C level shifter isolation

Tags: transistors, mosfet, pcb, digital-logic, analog

I am designing an FPGA-based SOM. There are I2C slave and master devices on the board. The I2C bus on the board includes an MCU that acts as a system manager and a bridge from UART to I2C, a PMIC device configured by I2C, a component containing an RTC and temperature sensor, the FPGA itself, the clock generator, and the output to the external environment from the mezzanine connector outside the board.

The FPGA has a power-up sequence. FPGA IOs are not supposed to rise before the VCCIO voltage, so I have to go to isolation on the bus. For this reason, I decided to make a simple MOSFET-based level shifter so that it would take up little space and be cheap.

I made a SPICE simulation for a component containing two N-channel MOSFETs in a single package. The line was designed to meet the fast-mode I2C standard. Already the RTC/temperature sensor component and FPGA are using 1.8 V; other devices are using 3.3 V.

In theory, I should be able to provide both isolation and level shifting, because if 1.8 V VCCIO is not available, the MOSFETs will be cut off and there will be no leakage from the 3.3 V I2C line to the FPGA pin (a leak that may cause problems).

However, in the simulation I made with the SPICE model offered by the manufacturer of the MOSFET, while there is no problem during normal operation when VCCIO is removed and there is no switching on the 3.3 V side, 3.1-odd V leakage appears on the FPGA side. Additionally, if there is switching on the 3.3 V side when there is no VCCIO, I still read 1.8 V on the FPGA side.

What exactly do you think is the reason for this? Am I missing something? What are your possible solution suggestions?

Note: All parasitics on the bus were made taking into account the FPGA's IBIS model, component datasheets, and possible path widths and lengths in the PCB stack.

Normal operation is the same for SCL and SDA:
[image: Normal operation is the same for SCL and SDA]

Normal operation, VCCIO side waveform:
[image: Normal operation, VCCIO side waveform]

Normal operation, 3.3 V side waveform:
[image: Normal operation, 3.3 V side waveform]

With no VCCIO (floating) and no switching:
[image: With no VCCIO (floating) and no switching]

VCCIO side waveform with no VCCIO (floating) and no switching (3.3 V side already showing flat 3.3 V):
[image: VCCIO side waveform with no VCCIO (floating) and no switching (3.3 V side already showing flat 3.3 V)]

Transistor drain current waveform with no VCCIO (floating) and no switching on the 3.3 V side:
[image: Transistor drain current waveform with no VCCIO (floating) and no switching on the 3.3 V side]

When there is no VCCIO (floating) and there is switching on the 3.3 V side:
[image: When there is no VCCIO (floating) and there is switching on the 3.3 V side]

VCCIO side waveform with no VCCIO (floating) and 3.3 V side switching (3.3 V side same as normal operation):
[image: VCCIO side waveform with no VCCIO (floating) and 3.3 V side switching (3.3 V side same as normal operation)]

Comment: There are dedicated ICs for these applications. Cheap, simple, realiable. See DigiKey/Mouser ... etc

Comment: Yes, I know. However, this solution is more logical for size, cost, and external component usage cases. I have already investigated dedicated level shifters and then made decisions this way.

Comment: Check Fairchilds FXMAR2102 - 1.2x1.4mm, 0.16€/pc @5kPcs, Output-Enable (Can be Handy) and no passives (If layout is done correct) required. Will neither be cheaper, nor simpler, nor more reliable with a discrete solution. Also think about your engineering time.

Comment: Oh come on, how did I miss this? I did a lot of research beforehand, I remember seeing something similar. But it made sense to try the discrete solution to push the 400p capacitance limit and for cheap isolation (discrete resistors were needed anyway, I didn't want to add an enable resistor and VCC line capacitors). However, this device seems to give exactly the effect I want in terms of isolation. Engineering time is always important, but maybe it was a little wasted this time, okay :)) Thank you very much for the suggestion. I will try this.

Comment: @electroeso Just be careful with that FXMAR2102 chip. They look good on paper and people put them on their design. Similar bi-dir auto-directional buffers are made by TI as well, and most questions here about them is why they don't work as expected, but the expectations are genrally unrealistic and the chip is used in an environment it cannot work properly. There are less smart I2C level shifting solutions that may work better because they are simpler.

Comment: Oh @Justme, you confused my mind . I have never found any spice model for FXMAR2102. My purpose was to verify this in the simulation and then go forward. But couldn't do it.  What do you prefer? Do you think I should proceed with the simple solution that I verified with Spice simulation or with a part that looks good on the datasheet?

Comment: @electroeso Depends on the situation. My concern is, your simulation showed about 3V on the 1V8 side too. Perhaps you are not simulating it properly. If you assume FET has tiny amount of capacitance between the pins, and 1V8 supply is floating, there will be nearly 0V over the FET pins as there is nothing to charge or discharge it, and thus both sides are nearly are at same voltage, and as one side is at 3.3V then other side is at 0V too. If VCCIO is 0V then it's 0V, not floating.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why your last waveform looks like that. I am able to simulate correctly. Here is my simpler test circuit.
[image]

The DMN2991UDR4 NMOS Spice model was downloaded from [here](https://www.diodes.com/spice/download/4973/DMN2991UDR4.spice.txt) and was renamed to `DMN2991UDR4.mod` and included in the circuit using the `.inc` directive. And here is the waveform.
[image]

| S1 | S2 | Outputs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ON | OFF | Both 0V |
| OFF | OFF | Both raise to 3.3V and 1.8V, respectively |
| OFF | ON | Both 0V |
| ON | ON | Both 0V |

Note: `V(sw1)` (red) is set to 2V instead of 1V like `V(sw2)` (cyan) just to make the waveforms clearer when plotted together. `V(sw1) = 2V` switches S1 OFF and `V(sw2) = 1V` switches S2 OFF.

Now, if the gate and the 1.8V side are pulled down to 0V like below
[image]

The waveforms become
[image]

The 1.8V side remains low (blue waveform) regardless of whatever signal that appears on the 3.3V side, which means the 1.8V side is isolated from 3.3V side like what you have expected.

**Edited**

If you need to wait till the FPGA to complete its power-up sequence and you are able to spare an I/O pin, then here is a solution using one PNP, one capacitor, and 2 resistors
[image]

And here is the waveforms
[image]

The FPGA turns ON (`FPGA_Ctrl=1.8V`) the voltage shifter when it is ready and then it is powered down (`FPGA_Ctrl=HiZ`) as shown in the purple waveform. It takes a while for the `C3` to discharge, but eventually the 1.8V side is isolated. The signal bumps you see when it is completely isolated are less than 90mV in the simulation.

Comment: Huge thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, you're missing a point. 1.8V side will be floating for a bit of time up to when the FPGA power-up sequence is done. Not grounding. Meanwhile, MCU will configure PMIC, so this means 3.3V is active before FPGA's 1.8V VCCIO rail, and isolating any voltage from FPGA IOs is critical. Because of simulating this scenario, I put a huge resistor on the 1.8V side. Because LTspice is ridiculous if you actually leave any node floating.

Comment: If you can spare an I/O pin then you can use my new circuit. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I edited again because I forgot that the FPGA_Ctrl pin must float when powered down.

Comment: Thank you so much. This PNP solution is very logical but not simple from my perspective (size and area are big issues for this design). I may use it if can't find a better solution.

Comment: Actually you can omit the PNP. You just need 1 capacitor and 2 resistors. The turn OFF period of the voltage shifter would be around 25usec (from my simulation). You can use 0201 (0.6mm * 0.3mm) capacitors and resistors if you are concern with the area occupied. You can pack them nicely and that would be roughly the size of the DMN2991UDR4. Also note that you need only one set to control all the voltage level shifters.